# React: How to redirect in a function in app?

Tags: reactjs

I have a logout function in app (same level as router) that's passed down to various pages so the user can logout from anywhere. How can I add a redirect when the function is called?

I tried using `this.props.history.push("/");` but get error `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Comment: Is it a functional component or Class based component? If functional you should exclude `this` like this: `props.history.push("/")`

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and edit your question. We need to see some code to help you, otherwise we can just guess.

Comment: Can you share the full component

Comment: @OnerT. It is class based component. Otherwise it will be `can't read property 'history' of undefined`. Most likely you forgot to wrap you component with `withRouter`

Answer (score 0):

**Use the (`withRouter`) high-order component**

Sample

```
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  ...
  handleSubmit=()=>{
    this.props.history.push("/path");
  }
  ...
}
export default withRouter(App);
```

[Live demo with sample code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-bre55)

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to create the function on the same level as the router. This works for sub-levels but doesn't appear to work in my case

Answer (score 0):

To answer to your question we need to know which router you are using and which version.

If you are using `react-router` you can have a look at https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-programmatically-navigate/